# Calling yahoo finance API from GAE (gaelyk)

Tags: google-app-engine, groovy, yahoo-api, gaelyk

I have a simple problem (but maybe tough answer), following:
I want to call yahoo finance api from gae (under gaelyk).
it is perfectly working in localmode but unfortunately when pushing to gae it fails. What is the reason? is google preventing from doing such things?
Thanks for any leads or answers.
(tip it is not tied to CORS unless yahoo does such things)

EnviableJimi

my call is: (params.symbol is populated accordingly as well as month, year and day)

```
def yahooUrl="http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=" + params.symbol +
"&a=" + (month+1)  +
"&b=" + day +
"&c=" + year   +
"&g=" + (params.resolution!=null?params.resolution.toLowerCase():"") +
"&ignore=.csv"
def content = new URL(yahooUrl).getText()
```

Comment: What fails exactly? What the return message?

Comment: in the log : error 500 from gae server

Comment: would be nice to see the logged failure

Comment: problem solved : it came from a timeout from yahoo servers and hence the 500 error, thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved : it came from a timeout from yahoo servers and hence the 500 error,

thanks all